# Compressed / abbreviated bibliography? (Biblatex or otherwise?)

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies

I'm writing a grant application, and I've been asked to compress my bibliography so that it looks something like this:

> 1. Smith, J. *Nature* **7**, 201-204 (1999). 2. Jones, B. *Cell* **17**, 364-369  
>     (2007). 3. Jackson, R. et al. *J Comp Bskt Weave* **32**, 123-190 (2010). 4. Parker, 
>     P. et al. *J Wall  Climb*, **10**, 17-21 (1973). [...]

First author name only (followed by et al.), abbreviated and italicised journal names, bold volume numbers, no line breaks so that the entire reference list is basically a single giant paragraph (I know, it's ugly as sin, but this is what I've been asked to do), etc.

I'm using biblatex because I need to print this bibliography in the middle of the proposal, and it just seemed easiest to use biblatex in that situation.  Is there any biblatex style that would do what I'm looking for?  Or failing that, a bibtex style and I'll figure out how to print the bibliography in the right place?  Or will I need to figure out how to roll my own?

Comment: I managed to get the `1.` to be not recognised as a numbered list by changing the *markdown* syntax into direct HTML code. Not sure if there's a better way...

Comment: Could you include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), please. I think I have an Idea, but I need to tweak it a little with your code.

Comment: See also [Removing Line Breaks in Bibliography compiled with Biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140787/35864) where a solution that does not use a list at all is discussed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This solution takes pretty much the same approach as Oleg's, but it avoids the `paralist` package as the one-paragraph list environments don't entirely get along with `biblatex`'s numeric citation label format. The document here also uses the contributed style package `biblatex-nature`, but any other numeric style could be applied.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=nature,maxnames=1,uniquelist=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

% Some field suppression via options
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{isbn=false,url=false,doi=false,eprint=false}

% One-paragraph bibliography environment
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
        \printfield{prefixnumber}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}%
      \ifentrytype{article}{% Suppress remaining fields/names/lists here
        \clearfield{title}}{}}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
      \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\mkbibitem}

% \mkbibitem just prints item label and non-breakable space
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mkbibitem}{\@itemlabel\addnbspace}
\makeatother

% Add breakable space between bibliography items
\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{\addperiod\space}

% et al. string upright (nature style applies \mkbibemph)
\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
    and
    test \ifmorenames
  }
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}{\finalandcomma}{}%
     \andothersdelim
     \bibstring{andothers}}
    {}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\section{Section title}
Filler text \parencite{bertram,glashow,aksin}.
\printbibliography
\section{Section title}
Filler text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you help!  I'll test out your approach in the morning as well.  (Not sure whose answer to accept here!)

Comment: @Winawer No problem. Aside from a harmless log warning, Oleg's answer is perfectly acceptable for your problem. Errors only arise if you pass nested optional arguments to `\inparaenum`. For example: `\inparaenum[ \printfield[<format name>]{labelnumber}]`.

Comment: This answer is surely more sophisticated. I'd have also avoided the `paralist`, if I'd know the `\@itemlabel` command :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a modification of the standard style `numeric`. If you use another one, this should be modified accordingly. The same goes for entry types other than `@article`.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{a1,
  author = {Smith, J.},
  journal = {Nature},
  volume = {7},
  pages = {201-204},
  year = {1999},
}
@article{a2,
  author = {Jones, B.},
  journal = {Cell},
  volume = {17},
  pages = {364-369},
  year = {2007},
}
@article{a3,
  author = {Jackson, R. and others},
  journal = {J Comp Bskt Weave},
  volume = {32},
  pages = {123-190},
  year = {2010},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\inparaenum[ \printfield{labelnumber}.]}
  {\endinparaenum}
  {\item}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\textbf{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\xpatchbibmacro{journal+issuetitle}
  {\usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}}
  {\usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
   \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
   \printfield{pages}%
   \clearfield{pages}}
  {}{}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

As Audrey noticed, it's even simpler with `biblatex-nature` style. You only need to modify the bib environment (so `xpatch` is not necessary):

```
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\inparaenum[ \printfield{labelnumber}.]}
  {\endinparaenum}
  {\clearfield{title}\item}
```

I also added the clearing of undesired fields, in this case only `title`.

Comment: +1 Aside from the one-paragraph requirement `biblatex-nature` is quite close to the desired style. It's unlikely the source `bib` file will be lacking titles; these can be suppressed in `\AtEveryBibitem` or the customized `bibliopgraphy` environment.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I added these to the answer.

Comment: That is *genius*, thanks! The biblatex-nature+modification gets me where I need to be. (Well, I have to go back and shorten all my journal titles, but that's my own stupid fault)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed something up, I had lying around, so formatting may not apply correctly. The style you wanted to reproduce is not part of [biblatex-chem](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-chem) But if you have already worked out a citation style already (how to format the bibliography), this still might help. (It is a fairly quick-and-dirty solution. Comments are very welcome.)

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{foo,
  title = {Foo},
  publisher = {the Press},
  year = {3000},
  author = {the Foo and another foo and the bar},
}

@ARTICLE{baz,
  author = {the Baz and another baz and the foo},
  title = {Baz},
  journal = {J. of Baz},
  year = {3001},
  volume = {1},
  pages = {22},
}

@ARTICLE{buz,
  author = {the Buz and the baz},
  title = {Buz},
  journal = {J. of Buz},
  year = {3001},
  volume = {1},
  pages = {22},
}

@BOOK{bar,
  title = {Bar},
  publisher = {the Press},
  year = {3002},
  author = {the Bar and the foo},
}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt,final]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
            style=chem-biochem,
            maxcitenames=1,mincitenames=1,
            ]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newcommand{\numberedfullcite}[1]{\cite{#1}~\fullcite{#1}}

\begin{document}

\leftline{\bfseries Bibliography:}

\noindent\numberedfullcite{foo} %
\numberedfullcite{baz} %
\numberedfullcite{buz} %
\numberedfullcite{bar}

\end{document}
```

It gives:
[image]