# Removing Line Breaks in Bibliography compiled with Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, line-breaking

I have a strict page limit on a paper I'm writing, and the page limit includes citations, so to save space I would like to remove the line breaks between entries in my bibliography:

```
[1] Dr. Seuss. *Horton Hears a Who!* Random House, 1954. [2] J. Lennon. *In His Own Write*.  Macmillan & Scribner, 1964. [3] L. Carroll. *Alice's Adventures in Wonderland*. Macmillan, 1864.
```

instead of

```
[1] Dr. Seuss. *Horton Hears a Who!* Random House, 1954.
[2] J. Lennon. *In His Own Write*.  Macmillan & Scribner, 1964.
[3] L. Carroll. *Alice's Adventures in Wonderland*. Macmillan, 1864.
```

At the moment, the biblatex commands I'm using are

```
\usepackage[firstinits=true,backend=bibtex,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false]{biblatex}
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \clearfield{pages}%
}
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\normalfont\footnotesize}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\begin{document}
\end{document}

\nocite{*}
\begingroup
\setlength\bibitemsep{0pt}
\setlength\bibnamesep{0pt}
\printbibliography[heading=none]
\endgroup
```

which I think explains why I want to use Biblatex instead of the paralist solution I've seen (and that I could not get to work with Biblatex).

EDIT I: Here are two screen shots showing the spacing differences.

No line break:
[image: No Line Break]
With line break:
[image: With Line Break]

Edit II:

Solved with

```
\usepackage{setspace}
...
\begin{spacing}{.5}
\printbibliography
\end{spacing}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You might want to try the following modification of the bibliography environment.

The bibliography will be printed unindented (`\noindent`), the `\unspace` removes the last space added in the bibliography, the `\printtext` part adds the label number followed by a space.

```
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\noindent}% or {} if you like indentation
  {\unspace}
  {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
     \printfield{labelprefix}%
     \printfield{labelnumber}}%
   \addspace}
```

If you use this, however, there will be no space before the label, we can add it by

```
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{\finentry\addspace}
```

The MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[firstinits=true,backend=bibtex,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false]{biblatex}
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \clearfield{pages}%
}
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\normalfont\footnotesize}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\noindent}
  {\unspace}
  {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
     \printfield{labelprefix}%
     \printfield{labelnumber}}%
   \addspace}
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{\finentry\addspace}

\begin{document}
  \cite{wilde,shore,springer}

  \printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{document}
```

yields
[image]

---

As you can see, this is not very clear and well arranged, so I would advise against doing this - especially in long bibliography lists.

---

Following jon's suggestion in the comment below, this might be better.
We add more space between the entries (a `\quad`) and print the label in bold.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[firstinits=true,backend=bibtex,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false]{biblatex}
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \clearfield{pages}%
}
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\normalfont\footnotesize}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\noindent}
  {\unspace}
  {\printtext[bold]{%
     \printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
       \printfield{labelprefix}%
       \printfield{labelnumber}}}%
   \addspace}
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{\finentry\quad}

\begin{document}
  \cite{wilde,shore,springer}

  \printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Agreed on the 'don't do it part', but, if it is needed, I think using a bigger horizontal space would be better.  Something like `\finentry\quad` will make the start of new entries more obvious.  I'd also recommend putting the `prefixnumber` and `labelnumber` in bold for the same reason.

Comment: THANK YOU moewe! You have just helped out a lot of people applying for the NSF GRFP this year! :D  (Thank you for your suggestion too jon)

Comment: Hi, I've just realized that the spacing between the entries in the bibliography is actually greater now; thus, the bibliography takes up more space!  Before, I was able to get 9 lines at the bottom of the last page in my paper (not including a space between the text and the bibliography) but now I can only get 7 lines.  Is there a way to compactify the bibliography and retain the no-line-break formatting?

Comment: @William The success of this method very much depends on the particular situation one is facing. The example entries above, for instance, take up only marginally more space in the standard bibliography setup; while very short entries like your example entries do benefit from the new setup. Could you elaborate on "the spacing between the entries in the bibliography is [...] greater now"? Do you mean line spread or just the space the bibliography takes up? You could use `\usepackage{setspace}` to reduce the line spread in the bibliography to save some precious space.

Comment: Hi, I have added screenshots to my original post.  I hope that makes what I was trying to say clearer.

Comment: @William Mhhh, the new set-up takes up less space than the old one, doesn't it? The space between the last line of the bibliography and the page number is larger. Have you actually tried putting more text on the page?

Comment: @moewe You are correct!  That problem was localized to me I think. Using setspace with .5 got it the way I wanted it.  Thank you so much moewe!

Comment: For some reason using this causes it to ignore the doi=false flag. Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: @Canageek That is very odd, indeed. I just ran a test with the example above and an entry with a DOI (`sigfridsson`) and the `doi` option worked as advertised. The code above should really have no influence on the `doi` option an its friends. Can you show an example of how it doesn't work for you?

Comment: @moewe I've posted a new question with a MWE http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272231/why-does-this-code-to-condesnse-the-bibliography-cause-it-to-ignore-the-doi-fals