# Inline bibliography avoiding the list format?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies

I'd like the output of `BibTeX` or `BibLaTeX` to be a inline bibliography (with entries separated e.g. just with bullets, see example below) avoiding the common list-based format. This is needed for posters. Usually I just copy-paste and then adapt the whole bibliography, but that's painstaking and error-prone. Any ideas?

Here's some MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    natbib=true,
    style=numeric,
    backend=biber,
    ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@article{Smith:01,
  author = {Smith, John},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Article title},
  journal = {Journal title},
  volume = {13},
  pages = {1--2}
}
@book{Mueller:02,
  author = {M{\"u}ller, Hans},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Book title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  address = {Address}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}    
\cite{Smith:01}, \cite{Mueller:02}   
\section*{``Flat'' bibliography}  
Hans M\"uller. \textit{Book title}. Address: Publisher, 2002. \raisebox{0.2ex}{$\bullet$} John Smith. ``Article title'' . In: Journal title 13 (2001), pp. 1--2.
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** Note that the "flat"/inline bibliography should also contain the numeric labels.

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: What's a "flat bibliography"? What's "the common list-based format"? This is the kind of question that would benefit from: (1) an image showing what you hope for; (2) at least some idea of (in `biblatex` terms) what bibliography style you require; and (3) some code to save people from needing to make assumptions that may be incorrect and/or uncalled for.

Comment: @jon: I imagine that `flat` means `inline`, one short reference after another one? Actually, I wondered too

Comment: @jon: I've edited my question. Sorry for the terminology being ad hoc. `biblatex` defines bibliography styles with `\list` in `\defbibenvironment{bibliography}`. That's why I called it list-based. As for "flat", I'd be grateful to learn the proper `biblatex` term. I don't like "flat" very much either.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140787/35864

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the answer to your edited question see here (the old version with explanations is left below).

Our bibliography environment can be even more mundane now

```
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\noindent}
  {\unspace}
  {}
```

The work is now done by `begentry` which prints the label

```
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
    \printfield{labelprefix}%
    \printfield{labelnumber}}%
  \setunit{\addspace}}
```

and `\finentrypunct` for the proper separation

```
\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{\addperiod\space}
```

There is no need for additional packages.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    natbib=true,
    style=numeric,
    backend=biber,
    ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\noindent}
  {\unspace}
  {}

\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
    \printfield{labelprefix}%
    \printfield{labelnumber}}%
  \setunit{\addspace}}

\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{\addperiod\space}

\begin{document}    
\cite{geer}, \cite{worman}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

With `\defbibenvironment` we can define how the bibliography is set ourselves. See also the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) §3.6.8 *Bibliography Headings and Environments*, p. 80 and §4.2.2 *Bibliography Environments* pp. 127-128.

In our case, [`paralist`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/paralist)'s `inparaitem` environment seems fit, so we go with

```
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\inparaitem}
  {\unspace\endinparaitem}
  {\item}
```

To make sure we don't get into trouble with the spacing at the end we redefine `\finentrypunct`

```
\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{\addperiod\quad}
```

of course, `\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{\addperiod\space}` is even more compact.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    natbib=true,
    style=numeric,
    backend=biber,
    ]{biblatex}
\usepackage{paralist}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\inparaitem}
  {\unspace\endinparaitem}
  {\item}

\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{\addperiod\quad}

\begin{document}    
\cite{geer}, \cite{worman}
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately `enumitem`'s `itemize*` environment did not like being used in `\defbibenvironment`, so I went with `paralist` in the above.

Comment: @Timm You could change the `{\item}` line to read `{\item \cite{\thefield{entrykey}} }` or better to `{\item\space\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{\printfield{prefixnumber}\printfield{labelnumber}}\space}`.

Comment: Thanks!! That's almost what I'm looking for. Two questions remain: how to add the numeric label and how to remove the first bullet?

Comment: You see, your image was slightly confusing me there, I will edit the question in a moment and find a more concise solution.

Comment: @Timm See the updated answer please, that seems to be the cleanest solution.

Comment: I was also trying with enumitems inline list but was not successfull, do you have any idea why that would not work, @moewe?

Comment: @MaxNoe Not really, no. I suppose it has to do with the way `itemize*` and friends are defined in `enumitem.sty` that the normal approach does not work. But I cannot really find the reason for this. I was hoping someone might come along and explain it if I added this observation.

Comment: I would replace the `\addspace` with `\addnbspace`, so that a label is not the last thing in a line.

Comment: @MaxNoe Fair point. Just for future reference, Max would replace `\setunit{\addspace}` in `\renewbibmacro*{begentry}` by `\setunit{\addnbspace}`.