# Remove all linebreaks in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, biber

Is it possible in biber to remove the linebreaks between bibligraphy entries, i.e. to have an appearance like:

> **[1]** So & So, Journal, 1999. **[2]** John Doe, Journal, 2001. **[3]** ...

rather than the usual

> **[1]** So & So, Journal, 1999.
>
> **[2]** John Doe, Journal, 2001.
>
> **[3]** ...

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140787/35864. There are also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124513/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/250204/35864.