# Bibliography with each entry not on a new line?

Tags: biblatex, line-breaking

Is it possible to get Biblatex (or bibtex, I can change) to put out a citation with each entry *not* on a new line?

Right now I have something that looks like:

```
1. Katz, M. J.; Ramnial, T.; Yu, H.-Z.; Leznoff, D. B. J. Am. Chem. Soc. 2008, 130, 10662–10673.
2. Lefebvre, J.; Korcok, J. L.; Katz, M. J.; Leznoff, D. B. Sensors 2012, 12, 3669–3692.
```

What I need is

```
1. J. Am. Chem. Soc. 2008, 130, 10662–10673. 2. Sensors 2012, 12, 3669–3692.
```

Now, removing the names seems pretty easy (as a last resort I can just do a find and replace in the bib file to get rid of them), but I have no idea how to make a super condensed block of citations. Is there an easy way to do this, or will I have to do it manually?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140787/removing-line-breaks-in-bibliography-compiled-with-biblatex

Comment: @lockstep Dammit, my googlful is failing me, that is two duplicates in a row.