# Why does this code to condense the bibliography cause it to ignore the DOI=false flag?

Tags: biblatex

I need a very, very condensed works cited section, so I'm using [this code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140792/7880) by @moewe. However, for some reason all of a sudden it ignores the `doi=false` flag.

MEW:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Allows UTF8 input. 

\begin{filecontents}{MWE.bib}
@article{VESTA,
author = "Momma, Koichi and Izumi, Fujio",
title = "{{\it VESTA3} for three-dimensional visualization of crystal, volumetric and morphology data}",
journal = "J. App. Cryst.",
year = "2011",
volume = "44",
number = "6",
pages = "1272--1276",
doi = {10.1107/S0021889811038970}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-acs,doi=false,articletitle=false,pageranges=true,biblabel=parens,autocite=superscript,url=false,isbn=false]{biblatex}
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \clearfield{pages}%
}
\addbibresource{MWE.bib}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\noindent}
  {\unspace}
  {\printtext[bold]{\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
    \printfield{prefixnumber}%
    \printfield{labelnumber}}}
    \addspace}
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{\finentry\quad}

\begin{document}

This is a test text.\cite{VESTA}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because `biblatex-acs` normally suppresses DOIs, but prints them regardless of what the `doi` option says if the `pages` field is missing. Since in the MWE you remove the `pages` field via `\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{pages}}` you always get the DOI.

The best way is probably to get rid of the

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \clearfield{pages}%
}
```

in your code. Alternatively, we can force `biblatex-acs` to always respect the `doi` option with

```
\renewbibmacro*{note+pages}{%
  \printfield{note}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pages}%
}
```

Comment: The `\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{pages}}` was only in my answer to [Removing Line Breaks in Bibliography compiled with Biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140787/35864) because it was in the original MWE by the OP, it does not as such make the bibliography (much) more compact. The important code is the `\defbibenvironment{bibliography}` bit and the `\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{\finentry\quad}`.

Comment: This was also helpful as I just noticed that the pages were missing (I was writing in a huge rush to get someone a draft.) This fixed both problems, thank you.