# How to create a "running" (= non-list) bibliography?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I want to create a "running" bibliography.

That means that each entry do not start at a new line after a carriage return, but is simply separated from the previous one with a symbol I want to chose (e.g. | or ♦) and runs on the same line (see example below).

I am using `BibLaTeX` (and thus `biber`) with `style=authoryear`.

[image: expected output]

**Question:** Is there already a `bibstyle` that could create this output?

N.B.: I *know* this is far from optimal in terms of readability/usefulness and shall break several rules of how to build a good bibliography. But, you know, I might have a rebel instinct sometimes `(-;`

---

If needed here is a MWEB

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
    \PassOptionsToPackage{backend=biber, citestyle=authoryear, natbib=true}{biblatex}
    \usepackage{biblatex}
    \usepackage{filecontents}

    \begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
        @BOOK{Dummy1,
            author    = "John Doe",
            title     = "The Book without Title",
            publisher = "Dummy Publisher",
            year      = "2016"
        },
        @ARTICLE {Dummy2,
            author  = "Erika Musterman",
            title   = "How to be everywhere?",
            journal = "Even in newspaper",
            year    = "1984"
        }
    \end{filecontents}

    \addbibresource{jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    Some text \citet{Dummy1}. And even more content \citep{Dummy2}.

    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: like this http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140792/36296 ?

Comment: @samcarter yep!