# Using natbib, make new entries not start at new line

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

There are several examples for making bibliographies not start each entry with new lines (e.g., [Removing Line Breaks in Bibliography compiled with Biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140787/removing-line-breaks-in-bibliography-compiled-with-biblatex) and [Removing Line Breaks in Bibliography compiled with Biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140787/removing-line-breaks-in-bibliography-compiled-with-biblatex)).  Generally (as in my case) this is because of page limits in grant applications.

However, all the ones I've found use a numbered citation system, while I want to use natbib and have the author's name appear.  I can't seem to make these work with natbib.

This example (from [Removing Line Breaks in Bibliography compiled with Biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140787/removing-line-breaks-in-bibliography-compiled-with-biblatex)) works if the natbib command is commented out.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[firstinits=true,backend=bibtex,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false]{biblatex}
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \clearfield{pages}%
}
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\normalfont\footnotesize}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\noindent}
  {\unspace}
  {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
    \printfield{prefixnumber}%
    \printfield{labelnumber}}
    \addspace}
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{\finentry\addspace}

\begin{document}
  \cite{wilde,shore,springer}

  \printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to make it work with natbib?

Comment: I eventually didn't need the space, so ultimately I did not need this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tell `biblatex` with option `natbib` to use `natbib`.

With the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{natbib} % <================================================

\usepackage[%
  giveninits=true,
  backend=bibtex,
  doi=false,
  isbn=false,
  url=false,
  natbib,     % <=======================================================
]{biblatex}
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \clearfield{pages}%
}
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\normalfont\footnotesize}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\noindent}
  {\unspace}
  {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
    \printfield{labelprefix}%
    \printfield{labelnumber}}
    \addspace}
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{\finentry\addspace}


\begin{document}
  text \cite{wilde,shore,springer} text

  \printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{document}
```

I get only one warning (okay) and the resulting pdf:

[image: resulting pdf]