# Natbib aasjournal bibstyle without DOI

Tags: natbib, bibliographystyle, aastex

How can I prevent `natbib` with `aasjournal` style to print the DOI and how can I make it print all references without a `\newline` for each one (in order to save space)?

I have been trying to modify a few lines in [aasjournal.bst](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/aastex/aasjournal.bst) and I can manage to prevent DOI to show up but then also other (apparently unrelated) journal details are missing such as issues and pages.

I am using `\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about `.bst` files; however, a *cludgey* way to get rid of the doi (and other urls) in the `aasjournal` bibliography style is to change the following commands from:

```latex
  "\providecommand{\url}[1]{\href{#1}{#1}}"
  write$ newline$
  "\providecommand{\dodoi}[1]{doi:~\href{http://doi.org/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}"
  write$ newline$
  "\providecommand{\doeprint}[1]{\href{http://ascl.net/#1}{\nolinkurl{http://ascl.net/#1}}}"
  write$ newline$
  "\providecommand{\doarXiv}[1]{\href{https://arxiv.org/abs/#1}{\nolinkurl{https://arxiv.org/abs/#1}}}"
  write$ newline$
```

to

```latex
  "\providecommand{\url}[1]{\href{#1}{#1}}"
  write$ newline$
  "\providecommand{\dodoi}[1]{}"
  write$ newline$
  "\providecommand{\doeprint}[1]{}"
  write$ newline$
  "\providecommand{\doarXiv}[1]{}"
  write$ newline$
```

In my copy of the file, this begins on line `1776`. Removing the `newline$` commands from the file won't change the line spacing.

To change the spacing in the bibliography, the `natbib` package has a useful command to change the separation between bibitems (see [this Stack answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98557)). If using `aastex`, I believe `natbib` is already loaded.

```
\usepackage{natbib}  % skip if already loaded
\setlength{\bibsep}{2pt}
```

To completely remove the new line and have the entries simply listed, there is a solution which works with aastex on {TeX|Stackexchange} [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/384889/74468). Commenting out the two `\printfield` commands will remove the added line numbers. **This will override the `aasjournal.bst` style.**

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work. However, even with `\setlength` each bibitem starts on a new line, which is precisely what I don't want. I'd need all items to be continuous like text. Do you also know how to add "et al." for more than two authors?

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the "without a \newline" part. I will need to update the answer above, but (a) solution can be found in the tex.stackexchange answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/384889/74468). It's pretty easily modifiable and it works with aastex. This will not work with `.bst` files, but you can lookup how to modify biblatex styles. A jumping off point with would be [this useful post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61958/74468).