# Put references in two columns with minimal details for grant proposal

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex

I have a hard page limit for a grant proposal and would like to include a list of references split over two columns with minimal detail: Only 1st author et al, year, journal and DOI. Is it even possible? Any help is much appreciated!

[image]

Or have minimal details and run the references together.

[image]

Comment: Which document class do you employ? Are you familiar with the `multicol` package and its `multicols` environment?

Comment: I'm using \documentclass[A4paper,11pt]{report}. I have seen multicol before, yes that could be a good option, thank you. What do you think about the reduction of elements in the references themselves?

Comment: You may want to have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124513/35864 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140787/35864. Some of the styles of the `biblatex-chem` package drop the title of `@article`s by default making things more compact. For the number of names the options `maxnames` and `minnames` are relevant.

Comment: What did you finally settle with?

Comment: In the end I did it all by hand unfortunately @rainman

Comment: Same here. Writing grant proposal was tough enough for me.